# how to set status-bar and navigation-bar to be transparent from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-statusbar, android-navigation-bar

I'm using a fragment that has only a fragment container and trying to make status-bar and navigation-bar transparent to show the content of the fragment.

I'm used this style as activity theme but the result was a transparent status-bar that show the activity layout as shown

```
 <style name="AuthTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

[status-bar](https://i.ibb.co/Zfz3H26/IMG-20190709-131850.jpg)

[navigation-bar](https://i.ibb.co/vsGy7fQ/IMG-20190709-131907.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Add this lines in Activity oncreate() method before calling setContentView()

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    Window w = getWindow();
    w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
}
```

In your container layout add this

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```